# npm run test, is not running all my scripts in the sub folder under Integration folder in cypress framework,

Tags: npm, cypress

folder structure for integration folder  spec files is as below :

1. Cypress
2. integration
   -folder1
   -spec.js1
   -folder2
   -spec.js1

I have 10 sub folder under Integration folder, which has module wise scripts,
It runs only first 3 subfolders .spec files and generates the reports, but not all the subfolder scripts

i have cypress.json file mentioning the integration folder and the test files
in package.json- i have the scripts section mentioning the command for pretest and post test
scripts": {

```
"cypress:open": "cypress open",
"cypress:run": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/**/*,",
"pretest": "rimraf -r ./cypress/report/mochawesome-report/*",
"test": "npm run cypress-tests || npm run posttest",
"cypress-tests": "cypress run",
"posttest": "npm run merge-reports && npm run generate-htmlreport",
"merge-reports": "mochawesome-merge  cypress/report/mochawesome-report/*.json > cypress/report/report1.json",
"generate-htmlreport": "marge cypress/report/report1.json -f report -o cypress/report  --inline"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For an example, if your folder structure,

```
Fixture
Integration |--folder 1 --abcd.spec.js
            |--folder 2
            |--Folder 3 
Plugins
Support
```

Then you can mention your cypress.json file.

```
 "testFiles": ["**/*.spec.*"],
"integrationFolder": "./cypress/Integration",
```

then  try same command

Comment: i already have updated all the test files in cypress.json, but still it is not running all the script in all the sub folders under Integration folder, as shown below                                         
 "integrationFolder": "cypress/integration",
  "testFiles": [
    "TC1_test1Specs/*.spec.js",
    "TC2_test2Specs/*.spec.js",
    "TC3_test3Specs/*.spec.js",
    "TC4_test4Specs/*.spec.js",
    "TC5_test5Specs/*.spec.js",]